# how do i sort the following array/stdclass object in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object, sorting, stdclass

How do is sort this object by 'pos' in php?

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Mondays [pos] => 170 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Tuesdays [pos] => 299 )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Wednesdays [pos] => 355 )
[3] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Thursdays [pos] => 469 )
[4] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Fridays [pos] => 645 )
[5] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Mondays [pos] => 972 )
[6] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Tuesdays [pos] => 1033 ) 
[7] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Thursdays [pos] => 1080 )
[8] => stdClass Object ( [str] => Fridays [pos] => 1180 )
```

)

Comment: What do you want to sort the array by? str? pos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could probably use the [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) family of functions to sort it either on `str` or `pos`.  You have to define your own comparison function for that.

Pseudo-PHP example:

```
function compareItems($a, $b)
{
    if ( $a->pos < $b->pos ) return -1;
    if ( $a->pos > $b->pos ) return 1;
    return 0; // equality
}

uasort($yourArray, "compareItems");
```

Depending on your needs, [other comparison functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Try this function

```
function objSort(&$objArray,$indexFunction,$sort_flags=0) {
    $indices = array();
    foreach($objArray as $obj) {
        $indeces[] = $indexFunction($obj);
    }
    return array_multisort($indeces,$objArray,$sort_flags);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a little bit of explanation would be helpful?