# Sorting an Array of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I've read a few different topics on this ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146749/how-do-i-sort-the-following-array-stdclass-object-in-php) and the general doc info about [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) - which I believe is what I'm looking for), but the array is still being a bit stubborn (in my use-case).

Here's what I have:

```
// This sets an array of values to a variable
$collection_rows = get_field('collection_profiles');
```

This is the `print_r` of `$collection_rows`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [collection_profile] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 273
                            [post_author] => 1
                            [post_date] => 2012-03-26 07:53:45
                            [post_date_gmt] => 2012-03-26 13:53:45
                            [post_content] => 
                            [post_title] => Profile 1
                            [post_excerpt] => 
                            [post_status] => publish
                            [comment_status] => closed
                            [ping_status] => closed
                            [post_password] => 
                            [post_name] => profile-1
                            [to_ping] => 
                            [pinged] => 
                            [post_modified] => 2012-04-12 08:07:35
                            [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-04-12 14:07:35
                            [post_content_filtered] => 
                            [post_parent] => 0
                            [guid] => http://domain.com/?post_type=moulding_profiles&#038;p=273
                            [menu_order] => 0
                            [post_type] => moulding_profiles
                            [post_mime_type] => 
                            [comment_count] => 0
                            [ancestors] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [filter] => raw
                        )

                )

            [collection_profile_note] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [collection_profile] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 188
                            [post_author] => 1
                            [post_date] => 2012-02-17 15:24:24
                            [post_date_gmt] => 2012-02-17 21:24:24
                            [post_content] => 
                            [post_title] => Test Profile
                            [post_excerpt] => 
                            [post_status] => publish
                            [comment_status] => closed
                            [ping_status] => closed
                            [post_password] => 
                            [post_name] => test-profile
                            [to_ping] => 
                            [pinged] => 
                            [post_modified] => 2012-02-28 14:13:32
                            [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-02-28 20:13:32
                            [post_content_filtered] => 
                            [post_parent] => 0
                            [guid] => http://domain.com/?post_type=moulding_profiles&#038;p=188
                            [menu_order] => 0
                            [post_type] => moulding_profiles
                            [post_mime_type] => 
                            [comment_count] => 0
                            [ancestors] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [filter] => raw
                        )

                )

            [collection_profile_note] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [collection_profile] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 207
                            [post_author] => 1
                            [post_date] => 2012-02-23 13:35:55
                            [post_date_gmt] => 2012-02-23 19:35:55
                            [post_content] => 
                            [post_title] => Casing Test Profile
                            [post_excerpt] => 
                            [post_status] => publish
                            [comment_status] => closed
                            [ping_status] => closed
                            [post_password] => 
                            [post_name] => casing-test-profile
                            [to_ping] => 
                            [pinged] => 
                            [post_modified] => 2012-02-23 13:35:55
                            [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-02-23 19:35:55
                            [post_content_filtered] => 
                            [post_parent] => 0
                            [guid] => http://domain.com/?post_type=moulding_profiles&#038;p=207
                            [menu_order] => 0
                            [post_type] => moulding_profiles
                            [post_mime_type] => 
                            [comment_count] => 0
                            [ancestors] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [filter] => raw
                        )

                )

            [collection_profile_note] => 2
        )

)
```

(quite a doozey)

I'm looking to sort by an array key/value of `collection_profile_note`. What I've tried (up to this point) is:

```
$collection_rows = get_field('collection_profiles');
print_r($collection_rows);
if ($collection_rows) {
    echo '<h2>'.__('Profiles in Collection','roots').'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a->collection_profile_note == $b->collection_profile_note) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return $a->collection_profile_note < $b->collection_profile_note ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    usort($collection_rows, 'cmp');

    foreach($collection_rows as $collection_row) {
        // Extract single post value
        $collection_profile_field = $collection_row['collection_profile'];
        $collection_profile_page = isset($collection_profile_field[0]) ? $collection_profile_field[0]->ID : NULL;
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($collection_profile_page); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($collection_profile_page); ?></a> <?php echo $collection_row['collection_profile_note']; ?></li>
    <?php }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

and while it does change the order from what it displays without `uasort()` it doesn't order them how I'd like --> with function (2, 3, 1), without function (1, 3, 2)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please copy the object array from your browser's "view source" instead of from the screen as displayed. That will maintain all the linebreaks and whitespace we need to be able to see what the heck is in that block of madness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've implemented your sorting logic backwards:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a->collection_profile_note == $b->collection_profile_note) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $a->collection_profile_note < $b->collection_profile_note ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

From the [documentation for `uasort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Note that you're using this logic:

- If a < b, return 1 (in essence, telling the sorting function that a > b)
- If a > b, return -1 (in essence, telling the sorting function that a < b)

Comment: Thanks for the input - I updated the sorting logic - but the actual `foreach` statement (or `print_r()` for that matter) is still not outputting the arrays with the `collection_profile_note` in order (ascending). Made a quick Pastebin of this: http://pastebin.com/XJV9fMMr Thanks!

Comment: @Zach: Your sort logic is still backwards in your pastebin.

Comment: Ah, k that last part is now `return $a->collection_profile_note < $b->collection_profile_note ? -1 : 1;` but still no dice...

Comment: @Zach:  Your array structure also seems to be "an array of arrays" instead of "an array of objects".  You will need to modify your `cmp()` function to reflect this.  The notation `$a->collection_profile_note` assumes that `$a` is an object, when it's actually an array according to your `print_r()` output.  You should instead be comparing `$a['collection_profile_note']` and likewise for `$b`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks - figures why that implementation wasn't working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for you to sort the array in place?  It might be easier to break out the keys and values you're sorting on, sort those, then loop through that array (like so):

```
$sortme=array();
foreach( $collection_rows as $key=>$profile )
{
    $sortme[$key] = $profile['collection_profile_note'];
}

asort($sortme);

foreach( $sortme as $node=>$ignore ) 
{
    print_r($collection_rows[$node]);
}
```

Acknowledged this almost doubles the sorting time, but maybe enough for your needs?