# Sort and search an array of objects by one key

Tags: php, arrays, search, sorting

```
$data = Array ( 
           [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [top_level] => gold [sub_level] => coal ) 
           [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 3 [top_level] => bronze [sub_level] => dirt ) 
           [2] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 4 [top_level] => silver [sub_level] => aluminum ) 
    )
```

With PHP, how can I sort, for example, by [sub_level] ascending (or descending) to produce the following?

```
Array ( 
       [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 4 [top_level] => silver [sub_level] => aluminum ) 
       [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [top_level] => gold [sub_level] => coal ) 
       [2] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 3 [top_level] => bronze [sub_level] => dirt )  
)
```

Also, what would be the most efficient way to search [sub_level] for a specific value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort). In the function, compare the two properties you want and return an appropriate value. Consult the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146749/how-do-i-sort-the-following-array-stdclass-object-in-php) for more info.